# int &r = 1 is illegal ,but why const int &r = 1 is legal?

Tags: c++, reference

```
//  int &r = 1;
const int &r = 1;
cout << "r is " << r << endl;//output is 1
```

why const int &r = 1 is legal ?
because const？  please help me.   thanks in advance.
this is from C++ Primer 5th Edition exercise 2.27 (c)

Comment: Read more about [l-values & r-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29#lrvalue).

Comment: Because you've taken the reference to the constant `int` value - namely `1`. If you could modify the value of `1` then `1 + 1` wouldn't be `2` (and in some languages you can modify the value of `1`, but C++ isn't one of them).

Comment: Wow - a duplicate that points to a duplicate.